# Switch word positions on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, helper

Hello guys I need a bit help I neeed to switch words position on notepad++ they are like this.

> Grands|Albz

So I wanna to switch grand with albz to to other side without moving | to make it like this

> Albz|Grands

Whloe of the text any help please?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

do 
1)`cntrl+f`
2) go to the `replace` tab
3) type `Grands|Albz` in `find what:`
4) type `Albz|Grands` in `Replace with:`
5) Click on `Replace All` box(3rd from the top in right side in the pane) to replace all the occurrence.

If you want to make it generalize try below solution:
do 
1)`cntrl+f`
2) go to the `replace` tab
3) check the check box that say `Regular expression` at the bottom left corner. 
4) type `([A-Za-z]\w+)\|([A-Za-z]\w+)` in `find what:`
5) type `\2\|\1` in `Replace with:`
6) Click on `Replace All` box(3rd from the top in right side in the pane) to replace all the occurrence.

Comment: @Grands Albz: I updated the solution. It change the whole text now.

Comment: @Grands Albz: Please let me know if this does not satisfies your requirement.