# Notepad++ switch postions with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, cpu-word

Hello I need a help with my text which is like this

> Text1|Text2|Text3|Text4|Text5|Text6|Text7|Text8|Text9|Text10

So the text need to change it to like this:

> Text8|Text5|Text4|Text9|Text10|Text7

So change these texts postions and remove Text 1,2,3,6

Comment: Make capture groups for each piece, and then use `$8|$5|$4|$9|$10|$7` as the replacement string.

Comment: Im mostly a newbie to this regex can u explain it a bit more? On find what what shoud i type?

Comment: @4castle You should have posted that as an answer, i already have though. But in the future remember that the comment section is not for answers.

Comment: @Shadetheartist Yeah, I'm lazy, and just like to give hints when I feel that someone needs to do more research

Comment: Man Im big hurry for this I need this like urgent Ik on google theres like 1000  tutorials but I need it right now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch word postions in Notepad ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223508/switch-word-postions-in-notepad)

Comment: Rather than ask questions for the sake of getting people to do your work for you, how about actually learning from people's answers and learning regex for yourself? This isn't the place to ask 0-effort questions, nor do I think there is such a place.

Comment: Well shit @grands, i feel for ya, but you need to understand that this isn't a forum. Stackoverflow answers are intended to be viewed by other people too. So answers need to be somewhat generic.

Comment: You [asked this a year ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30783009/2564301) so I don't understand why the big hurry.

Comment: A year ago I just asked this man

Comment: You already got an answer from [Wiktor himself on basically the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39226011/5743988). Consider his answer carefully, learn from it, and you will never need to ask this kind of question again.

Comment: Well found it my self with find what ^(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)$ and replace it with $8|$5|$4|$9|$10|$7 thanks for nothing guys

Comment: @GrandsAlbz Good job :-)

Answer (score 0):

With regex you can use [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to replace stuff. In your case it might look like

*find*

```
(Text1)\|(Text2)\|(Text3)\|(Text4)
```

*replace*

```
$2|$1|$4|$3
```

*will result in*

```
Text2|Text1|Text4|Text3
```

So just apply this technique to your longer string and it should work just fine. Assuming you know how to order the results.

Comment: Man you relaise on my texts theres like a lot of lines and texts arnt all like text1 they are different

Comment: I was  hopping you to help me like this guy did here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223508/switch-word-postions-in-notepad

Comment: @grands You should have specified that in your question, i'm not just going to infer that.

Anyway, you need to find a pattern in what you are try to replace. Otherwise there is no way to do this with regex.

Comment: If this was for only one text I coud do it on manual way but theres a lot of lines thanks anyway

Comment: I did find what: (.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?) and replace with this $8|$5|$4|$9|$10|$7 and i get Text8|Text5|Text4|Text9|Text3|Text7|Text10|Text7Text10|